# Android - Dynamic form with Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` in an `Activity` and some text fields in the same `Activity`.

I want to make the text fields dynamic, and show specific fields, depends on the selection the user made on the `Spinner`.

I have this code in my class:

```
spinner_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){        

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (position == 1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

this isn't working.

Comment: you can dynamically set textview.setVisibility(true)  or false to display or hide based on your spinner item selection

Comment: @Bali but how do I get the spinner item selection position or value? the `position` variable as it is now in the code makes my app crash

Comment: use spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()

Comment: @Bali it still crashs. can you please give an example for how to prompt selection position everytime the user changes his selection?

Comment: If it is crashing please add the error message.